# REACT: How to bind and render multiple values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to REACT and I have been practicing a lot for the past week.  I have a VUE background.  I have created simple React form with just two fields.  I kind of know how state and binding works.  I am having a hard time rendering the values in my two fields.  Here's what I have so far:

```
class HelloWorld extends React.Component{
constructor(){
super()
this.state = {
  fname: '',
  lname: ''
}
this.handleClick = this.handleClicl.bind(this)
this.handleFname = this.handleFname.bind(this)
this.handleLname = this.handleLname.bind(this)
}

handleClick(){
console.log(this.state.fname);
console.log(this.state.lname);
}
handleFname(event){
this.setState({fname:event.target.value})
}
handleLname(event){
this.setState({lname:event.target.value})
}
render(){
return(
 <div>
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br />
    <input type="text" onChange={this.handleFname} id="fname" name="fname" value={this.state.fname} /><br />
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br />
    <input type="text" onChange={this.handleLname} id="lname" name="lname" value={this.state.lname} /><br /><br />
  <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
</div>
)
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <HelloWorld />,
 document.getElementById("root")
)
```

What am I doing wrong?  Please keep it very simple.  No need to add es6.  Simple is the only way I can understand at this point.

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/e878dd7413566cad8c1a46a5a83b6648?editors=0011)
Thanks!

Comment: Please, for the sake of all here on SO, yours and everyone reading the code after you: USE indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all your functions are single line I would suggest you to put them straight on the onChange prop:

```
OnChange={(e) => this.setState({lname:event.target.value})}
```

Do it with handleFname and handleLname.

Just a little thing to improve performance when app gets bigger!

Answer (score 1):

You had a typo in your binding:

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClicl.bind(this)
                                  ^
```

Should be

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
```

Comment: Thank you!  Is there a better way to do the form?  What if I had 50 fields? Do I bind and setState 50 times?  Thanks!

Comment: You can use libs to do this for you (you can search google for react form libraries, there are plenty).

Comment: If you use ES6 arrow functions you don't have to manually bind. Turn your functions into arrow functions.

Comment: Now the page is bland but not errors. anyone know why?  https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/e878dd7413566cad8c1a46a5a83b6648

Comment: I don't see any issues there... regardless - you should not log the `event`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the typo stated in other answer, I wanted to also give you a nice tip. You can use this arrow notation so you don't have to manually bind `this` to the function:

```
handleFname = (event) => {
    this.setState({fname:event.target.value})
}
```

By using this, you don't have to bind the `this` all the time. It's done automatically under the hood.

Note: Constructor is an exception for this, it needs to be defined as you have it already.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to bind, you can just use arrow functions, which are bound automatically.
For example instead of

```
handleClick () {

}
```

write

```
handleClick = () => {

}
```